# import working locally but not after install usinging pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, packaging, pypi

I was trying to publish a package then install using `pip3` and I got this error about importing a module:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/luanrv/codes/tmp/poc-pypkg/poc_pypkg/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

`__main__` file:

```
import utils

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('print from __main__')
    utils.display_msg()
```

the same happens for `from utils ...` and `from .utils ...`.

I don't get much time to understand python's packaging already. Would anyone aux me to solve this?

Comment: I am using `Poetry` to build and publish the package.

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? Where is the module located relative to the program?

Comment: Have you tried `from poc_pypkg import utils`?

Comment: @AMC sure. the path is poc_pkg > `_init/main__.py` + `utils.py` (poc_pkg inside of his parent poc-pkg).

Comment: @DustinIngram it does not worked even locally.

Comment: Do you have the package installed locally? `pip install -e .` in the same directory as `setup.py`.

Comment: @DustinIngram I am using Poetry to manage the distribution so the package does not have a `setup.py` file. I just ran it using `python3 path` or through installation from **pip**.

Comment: Ok then, `poetry add --path .` from the main directory. Running `python3 path` won't work with what I suggested unless your package is installed.

Comment: @DustinIngram `from poc_pypkg import utils` worked as expected, locally and after publishing/installing using pip. I missed up and tried to run using `python` instead of `python3`, what ran python2 causing the error on importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from poc_pypkg import utils` worked as expected, locally and after publishing/installing using pip. I missed up and tried to run using `python` instead of `python3`, what ran python2 causing the error on importing.